# I am trying to get the access token for my worker application but I get "The requested resource was not found." error message

Tags: python, api, access-token

I am making a POST request to the PingOne API (According to their [guide](https://apidocs.pingidentity.com/pingone/platform/v1/api/#post-get-a-worker-application-access-token)) in Order to retrieve my application access token. using 'client_credentials' as a grant type. 
I provided the request with it's all required parameters , and still getting the following error:

```
> /usr/local/bin/python3.7 "/Users/iaburmaileh/Desktop/APIs requests to PingOne/POST_GET_a_Worker_Application_Access_Token.py"
b'\n{       \n\t"id":"77F5305F-9961-4F8F-B8F7-E0E5FDA4FE41",\n\t"code": "NOT_FOUND",\n\t"message":"The requested resource was not found."\n}\n'
Process finished with exit code 0
```

here is my code (** my env and app are for demo and testing purposes , so no worry sharing their variables)

```
import requests

apiPath = 'api.pingone.com/v1'
envID = '5bb98115-61c7-4964-96bf-4d2c3a34756b'
appID = 'db04865b-9ab0-448e-a89a-f3cb473ddc7f'
appSecret = 'c_5XTOw6Sh-ei6cHLhvoneoVn-86t.zY1Df7YWcIUfpkN4gTjp1A7QjWUwlEpofp'

url = f"https://{apiPath}/{envID}/as/token"

payload = 'grant_type=client_credentials'
headers = {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'Authorization': f'Basic {appID}:{appSecret}'
}


response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Any idea how to fix this ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I got a positive result trying this POST:

(EDIT: I think I put the GET result before.)

I switched up the payload structure to a key-value collection for readability.

```
authPath = f'https://auth.pingone.com'
envID = '5bb98115-61c7-4964-96bf-4d2c3a34756b'
appID = 'db04865b-9ab0-448e-a89a-f3cb473ddc7f'
url = f"{authPath}/{envID}/as/authorize"

payload = {
        "response_type":"code",
        "client_id":f"{appID}",
        "redirect_uri":"https://example.com",
        "scope":"openid profile p1:read:user",
    }

headers = {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = requests.request("POST",
                            url,
                            headers = headers,
                            data = payload
                            )
```

Checking status code on response:

```
In [19]: response.status_code
Out[19]: 200
```

And the HTML:

```
In [21]: print(response.text)
```

Output:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" class="app-container" style="display: none;">
      <div class="page brand-background">
        <div class="page__content" id="page-ui-container"></div>
        <div class="page__footer brand-footer-color">
          <!-- Â© Copyright 2003-2020 Ping Identity. All rights reserved. -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks , But how to actually get the application access token?